# How to recover from abandoned connections?

Tags: tomcat, jdbc, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate, tomcat-jdbc

I had long running queries in production because of which connections getting closed/abandoned. As a result I updated removeAbandonedTimeout to 1800 sec. After this, 95% of the issue is gone. But very randomly, once or twice a month I am still getting connection abandoned errors.

The problem here is retrying after a wait time of 15 sec after catching this exception is not helping resolve the issue. The subsequent queries are immediately failing with connection abandoned exception.

My current pool configuration:

```
maxActive=50; 
maxIdle=1;
minIdle=0; 
initialSize=0; 
maxWait=10000; 
testOnBorrow=true; 
testOnReturn=false; 
timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=5000; 
minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=2000; 
testWhileIdle=false; 
testOnConnect=false; 
validationQuery=SELECT 1; 
validationQueryTimeout=-1; 
validationInterval=30000; 
removeAbandoned=true; 
removeAbandonedTimeout=1800; 
logAbandoned=true;  
jdbcInterceptors=ConnectionState;StatementFinalizer;ResetAbandonedTimer;
```

#### Replication

Database used: PostgreSQL

I changed `removeAbandonedTimeout` to `30sec`. The first pg_sleep failed as it exceeded timeout and entered catch block. My expectation was, since the connection is removed by background abandonedTimer, the next pg_sleep(10) should request a new connection and should get executed successfully as `testOnBorrow` is true. So I tried sleeping the current thread for 30 sec and executed the next pg_sleep. None of my catch or finally block statements are executing.

```
try {
  jdbcTemplate.execute("select pg_sleep(40)");
} catch(DataAccessException e) {
  LOGGER.info(e.getMessage(), e);
  Thread.sleep(30000);
  jdbcTemplate.execute("select pg_sleep(10)");
  LOGGER.info("Executed fall back case");
} finally {
  jdbcTemplate.execute("select 1");
}
```